# Is there a web based terminal/ssh client?

Tags: software-recommendation, command-line

I'm at a library, and all of the computers are Windows based.  I'm sshing into my Ubuntu box somewhere else. The terms of service says "You may not make any changes to system files." However, when I ssh into my Ubuntu box, it might "look" like I'm hacking, since I've had a few people (including I presume the library supervisor) look at my computer funny when I opened a website where the text was a monospaced font and the website background was black. Running Command Prompt will certainly be considered to be hacking if looking at a website was.

If I'm sshing into my box it appears as though I'm "hacking" into the computer. I'd like to somehow do it in a web browser with nice happy looking text, so that it actually represents what I'm doing; I'm not going to hack into the computer, I'm only using a computer somewhere else.

Comment: firefox or internet explorer?  Are they locked-down to prevent you installing add-ons/active-x controls?

Comment: Wikipedia: [Web Based SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web-based_SSH)

Comment: Firefox, Internet explored if I haveee to

Comment: If you can run files, you can use a portable version of PuTTY.

Comment: Another option would be to use something like logmein/gotomypc/RealVNC/[guacamole](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3240652/383694) (a browser launched/based VNC) to connect to another computer (such as your home PC) that you can run a VNC server (maybe on port 80/443) and an SSH session on, convoluted but may be easier for you. Use the browser as a VNC client to connect to a computer setup with a non-hacker looking gui.

Comment: For those that are searching for an answer to this, please keep in mind that you should use *extreme* caution when attempting to "man-in-the-middle" your security.  You should either self-host the solution or absolutely *trust* the third-party that is providing the SSH/terminal solution, as it will likely be possible for them to obtain any and all secrets/keystrokes/etc.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because (a) it asks for web-based software to be used on *Windows*, (b) the fact that it is being used to access an Ubuntu server isn't relevant (could be any target server), (c) It's incredibly difficult to verify that the websites referenced in the answers are *safe*

Comment: Also note that this question is being discussed on [Meta](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/20276/1165986)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If the Library is using Firefox and has the ability to install add-ons, try [FireSSH](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firessh/) - its a javascript based SSH client.

[image]

Comment: Also see: http://askubuntu.com/q/48515/17789

Comment: also available for Chrome

Comment: It says, No longer available for Firefox

Answer (score 9):

What you'll probably want to do, is to install a HTML-based terminal emulator. There are several (many) to choose from. That will give you a text field in a webpage (such as the one I'm currently typing into) and that will run on your system.

This is a list of such applications, in no particular order. I have little or no experience with these:

- http://anyterm.org/
- http://scott.yang.id.au/2006/04/ajaxterm-terminal-emulation/
- http://code.google.com/p/shellinabox/

You can see live demos of the three at the bottom of this page: http://anyterm.org/demos.html

All of these will work in any browser. Probably even IE4 :)

Answer (score 9):

If you're on Google Chrome/Chromium, you could give [**Secure Shell**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/secure-shell/pnhechapfaindjhompbnflcldabbghjo) a shot. It is a complete terminal emulator and a SSH client.
It and is developed by Google, and runs offline :)

> Secure Shell is an xterm-compatible terminal emulator and stand-alone
>   ssh client for Chrome.  It uses Native-Client to connect directly to
>   ssh servers without the need for external proxies.

[image]

You could also go with another extension, [**Devtools Terminal**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/devtools-terminal/leakmhneaibbdapdoienlkifomjceknl), which is a terminal emulator.

<sup>Note : This one requires a `npm-install` though. [Details](http://blog.dfilimonov.com/2013/09/12/devtools-terminal.html)</sup>

[image]

Happy SSHing :)

Comment: This answer doesn't address the issues mentioned in the question, however +1 because it absolutely answers the question title.

Answer (score 7):

Try this: [**tty.js**](https://github.com/chjj/tty.js) --- A terminal for your browser, using node/express/socket.io

Features:

- Tabs, Stacking Windows, Maximizable Terminals
- Screen/Tmux-like keys (optional)
- Ability to efficiently render programs: vim, mc, irssi, vifm, etc.
- Support for xterm mouse events
- 256 color support
- Persistent sessions

Comment: how to install it ? is it in-built or have to install ?

Comment: @Jai The above link has all the information you need. Just `npm install tty.js` to install and `tty.js` to start serving.

Answer (score 2):

I use ShellInAbox to access my pc from behind very restrictive firewall using just my browser. I also configure it to go over https like I've wrote here:

[ShellInAbox with https using your browser](http://www.techytalk.info/remote-cli-access-to-ubuntu-pc-using-web-browser-through-authenticated-https/)

Also you needed to use dynamic dns service provider like dyndns to be able to pinpoint your PC.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to recommend [GateOne](https://github.com/liftoff/GateOne), powerful and snappy. Author has Docker image as well for easy setup.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I'm the primary developer for Shellvault.

Another option is [Shellvault](https://www.shellvault.io), a web-based cloud SSH client that you don't have to download or set up yourself. It has terminal multiplexing, it looks nice by default, and since it's cloud-based, you can administer your servers from any computer without setting up SSH on a new machine.

[image: Shellvault.io terminal interface]

Shellvault is a Software-as-a-Service, so it's not free, but it has free trial so you can see if you like using it. After the 7-day trial, a subscription costs $5/month.

Answer (score 2):

This project is no longer available, but another option was: [https://bashify.io](https://web.archive.org/web/20211230143942/https://bashify.io/) [the current website is an unrelated image sharing and link shortener].

It was a Software as a Service. It used to run an SSH in the web browser completely installation free.

Disclaimer: I'm the developer.

Answer (score 0):

You should try Bastillion - https://www.bastillion.io You can use multiple terminals simultaneously (like tmux).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [Serfish Console](https://www.serfish.com/console/), as it uses ssh and requires no installation. You could also try Chrome Remote Desktop, as it works from any internet-connected computer, as long as you install the software on the computer you want to connect to. Chrome Remote Desktop also lets you use the desktop on the computer you are connecting to, and does not require port forwarding. If you just want basic SSH, then try Serfish Console.

Answer (score 0):

I use [WeTTY](https://github.com/butlerx/wetty), which uses the `xterm.js` library.

It's available both for local installation and as a [Docker container](https://hub.docker.com/r/wettyoss/wetty).

[image]