# Any apps for hosting a terminal app as a website?

Tags: command-line, hosting

I'm building a command line utility and one of my clients (who's not so computer savvy) wants to have access to it.

I was wondering, is there anything available that would let me redirect stdin/stout for a terminal app to a port as a website? This would save me a lot of time. Surely, there must be an Ubuntu one-liner that can accomplish such a feat...

Thanks for any pointers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is slightly more complicated than simply "redirecting stdin/stdout" to a port.

What you need is basically a shell session to your server with a client which runs inside a browser. [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48515/is-there-a-secure-web-shell-for-my-server) links to two such shells, [AjaxTerm](http://antony.lesuisse.org/software/ajaxterm/) and [WebShell](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~mressl/webshell/installation.html)

> Ajaxterm is a web based terminal. It was totally inspired and works
>   almost exactly like http://anyterm.org/ except it's much easier to
>   install

[image]

What worries me a bit is that both programs were last updated in 2008, which in web-years like 50 years ago. Please report back if you manage to run any of them.

A newer and seemingly more supported option is **Shell In A Box**:

> Shell In A Box implements a web server that can export arbitrary
>   command line tools to a web based terminal emulator. This emulator is
>   accessible to any JavaScript and CSS enabled web browser and does not
>   require any additional browser plugins. Most typically, login shells
>   would be exported this way:  shellinaboxd -s /:LOGIN
>
> This command starts a web server at http:// localhost :4200 that allows
>   users to login with their username and password and to get access to
>   their login shell.
>
> All client-server communications are encrypted, if SSL/TLS
>   certificates have been installed.

It is even available in Ubuntu repositories and can be installed with

```
sudo apt-get install shellinabox
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for- Perfect answer- Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

actually you can upload Application into your [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/) account as PPA . All your clients can access the application by adding it's PPA .

For more information read these things

[Packaging](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging)

[Code](https://help.launchpad.net/Code)

One more choice is you can upload your application into dropbox .

Comment: Thanks, but I'm referring to hosting an app through a port, so a user can interact with the app through a website. I am not referring to simply "uploading an app" to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [Gate One](https://github.com/liftoff/GateOne)?  It's a web-based terminal emulator.  You can configure it to automatically launch your terminal application whenever a user connects/opens a new terminal.  Here's a screenshot showing off the automatic syntax highlighting of syslogs:

[image]

You can also do cool stuff with it like display images, play sound files, and whatnot.  It also supports Unicode and foreign-language input (IME) if your users are international.