# Need a web shell

Tags: server, ssh, apache2

I'm looking for a web service that hosts a simple shell that I can use. I need to be able to update the server through it and such. Many of the links in a previous incarnation of this question (see [Is there a secure web-shell for my server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48515/is-there-a-secure-web-shell-for-my-server)) are broken, as it is now 4 years old. Others haven't been updated since 2006 and I feel in that time there will be huge incompatibility issues, if not security implications.

I'm looking for something easy to install (I have to do this via TeamViewer or RDP by connecting to a Windows machine then using putty to SSH into the server, and uploading files to the box using SCP or whatever isn't in my bucket list.). It needs to be capable of running on a port other than 80, 8080, 8081, 8181, and 81, since those are already in use, and it must run on another port out of the box (I can't do any initial setup on those ports, they need to be utilised for server uptime diagnostics I'm running).

Basically, I'd like to access this terminal from behind a secure firewall. I know the machine is safe (it's hosted in my house and I'm particularly careful with it) as it stands. I'd like to keep it that way, so if there's something that Canonical recommends, or that is lightweight and open source (to the extent that I could flick through 3-4 pages of code and see what it's doing), that'd be great. I'm not sure how difficult it is to implement something like this, so excuse me if that's an ambitious expectation.

To add to the above, I'd prefer a standalone server application, but would be happy to use something that integrates with apache2 or nginx provided I don't need to rebuild apache to add extensions or whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried http://anyterm.org/, seems like it will work for you.